# How to convert pandas dataframe using Unstack?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I want to convert the following DataFrame

[image: Data Frame 1]

into a new DataFrame

[image]

using pandas unstack function. Please help me out?

Comment: could you explain more what happened to dataframe 1 -> new dataframe?

Comment: Yeah so dataframe1 is pivoted around "itemid" and "segment" to give the new dataframe with some new add on columns (with p1 as prefix) containing p1 values from old dataframe with combition of pass number as suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", 1, 1, 10],
                   ["A", 2, 1, 20],
                   ["A", 1, 2, 30],
                   ["A", 2, 2, 40],
                   ["B", 1, 1, 50],
                   ["B", 2, 1, 60],
                   ["B", 1, 2, 70],
                   ["B", 2, 2, 80],
                   ["B", 1, 3, 90]], 
                  columns=["itemid", "segment", "pass", "p1"])

piv = df.pivot(["itemid", "segment"], "pass", "p1")
piv.columns = [f"p1_pass_{idx}" for idx in piv.columns]
piv.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  itemid  segment  p1_pass_1  p1_pass_2  p1_pass_3
0      A        1       10.0       30.0        NaN
1      A        2       20.0       40.0        NaN
2      B        1       50.0       70.0       90.0
3      B        2       60.0       80.0        NaN
```

I don't know whether the use of `unstack` is totally necessary for you.